# Number extraction from a string such as an integer or double

Tags: c++, string, getline, file-read, data-manipulation

I am having a difficult time thinking of a way to extract a number such as an int or a double from a string extracted from the getline() function.

//Example:

```
string data = "";
fstream inFile;
```

//File contains:

```
"Hello today is 83.3 degrees Fahrenheit."
```

// use the getline function

```
getline(inFile, data);
```

// extract number from string data

Thank You

Comment: Where would I start? Where can I find a tutorial on this?

Comment: Do you have access to C++11 or boost (both of which contain regular expressions)?

Comment: I cannot use those types of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following

```
getline(inFile, data);

std::istringstream iss;
iss.exceptions(std::istream::failbit | std::istream::badbit );

iss.str(data);
double dTemp = 0;

while( iss.good() ){

  try{
   iss >> dTemp;
   }      
  catch(std::istream::failure &e ){
   /* Do your error check over here */
  }

}
```

You make also want to read more about C++. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will totally fail as the first thing in OP's string is not the number, but a few random words.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you. We also need to check the failbit and badbit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sscanf if you are prepared to include cstdio.

The following man pages link will help you:-

http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

**Example**

```
char foo[] = "foo bar 12 baz";
int qux;
sscanf(foo, "foo bar %d baz", &qux); 
// qux will be assigned 12
```

or

```
char foo[] = "foo bar 12.5 baz";
double qux;
sscanf(foo, "foo bar %lf baz", &qux); 
// qux will be assigned 12.5
```

You will obviously need to tailor this to your scenario and take various safety issues into consideration.